# A proof that $a^n b^m $ for $n\neq m$ is not regular by using the pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

I am looking at $L=\{a^nb^m |n\neq m \}$. I would like to prove that $L$ is not regular.

This can easily done by assuming it is regular and looking at $\overline L$, or by using other theorems.

Despite that, I am interested in proving its not regular by using only the pumping lemma.

Let $k$ be my pumping constant. I tried several words, such as: $ ab^k$ (assuming $k>1$), $(ab)^ka$ or $a^{k!}b^k$, but all failed to disprove the irregularity of $L$.

I was wondering if I am looking for such a word in vain (Meaning, it satisfies the pumping lemma despite being not regular) or if I am missing the correct word.

Would kindly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: One of your attempts, the factorial, commes close. [Proving $L = \{a^nb^m \mid n, m≥0, n \neq m\}$ is not regular by use of Pumping Lemma](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99220/proving-l-anbm-mid-n-m%e2%89%a50-n-neq-m-is-not-regular-by-use-of-pumping)